# Determine is page is dirty using /proc/kpageflags

Tags: linux, memory, proc

`/proc/kpageflags` contains a 64-bit set of flags for each page, indexed by PFN. The flags are (from `fs/proc/page.c`, above `kpageflags_read`):

1. LOCKED
2. ERROR
3. REFERENCED
4. UPTODATE
5. DIRTY
6. LRU
7. ACTIVE
8. SLAB
9. WRITEBACK
10. RECLAIM
11. BUDDY
12. MMAP
13. ANON
14. SWAPCACHE
15. SWAPBACKED
16. COMPOUND_HEAD
17. COMPOUND_TAIL
18. HUGE
19. UNEVICTABLE
20. HWPOISON
21. NOPAGE
22. KSM
23. THP
24. BALLOON
25. ZERO_PAGE
26. IDLE

I have the flags on the physical memory page. I thought a physical page dirty is `flags & (1 << 4)` but I failed.

How do I know if the page is dirty?

Comment: Show the whole check line. Show your code. Show minimal reproducible example, needed to reproduce the issue. Is it `if ( flags & (1 << 4) )` or `if (flags & (1 << 4) != 0)` or `if ( (flags & (1 << 4)) != 0)`? Show the full code, at best including all the `#include` lines and opening the file and `main()` and parsing. `How do I know if the page is dirty?` - check for the 4th bit in the 32-bit words.

Comment: if (flag & (1<<4)) {...}

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/pagemap.txt        This is an introduction to kpageflags. Is it correct for me to understand? Thank you.